# How do I fetch a value from a table with such a structure in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table(browser)

```
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
| Users | Application |      Name      | Value  |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
| A1    | AA          | browsername    | IE     |
| A1    | AA          | browserVersion | 11     |
| A1    | AA          | browsername    | chrome |
| A1    | AA          | browserVersion | 60     |
| A1    | AA          | browsername    | safari |
| A1    | AA          | browserVersion | 11     |
| A2    | AA          | browsername    | IE     |
| A2    | AA          | browserVersion | 10     |
| A2    | AA          | browsername    | safari |
| A2    | AA          | browserVersion | 10     |
| A3    | AA          | browsername    | IE     |
| A3    | AA          | browserVersion | 9      |
| A3    | AA          | browsername    | chrome |
| A3    | AA          | browserVersion | 60     |
| A4    | AA          | browsername    | safari |
| A4    | AA          | browserVersion | 11     |
| A4    | AA          | browsername    | IE     |
| A4    | AA          | browserVersion | 10     |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
```

The user can use the application via any browser. 
I want to look into the users who used IE browser with 11 version. I'm not able to pick it up as both safari and IE has same versions. 
Can someone please suggest me how to get the data I require.

Comment: If those are all the columns you have in your table, the simple answer is: You can't. There is no query you can write that will **guarantee** that the order of the data is the same as in your post; thus no way you can get the result you want. Ideally, you need to correct the design of your table.

Comment: I've added an additional sample row to show a scenario that is (currently) impossible to deal with.

Comment: Do you have a column that gives you chronological data that allows you to link the name-version rows together? An identity column is suboptimal, but would also do as long as no inserts were rolled back. If this is not possible because this is pre-aggregated data, change the process so the name and version occur in the same row as columns -- anything else is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select user, application
from t
where name in ('browsername', 'browserVersion')
group by user, application
having sum(case when name = 'browsername' and value = 'IE' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when name = 'browserVersion' and value = '11' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 ;
```

Comment: This works, until someone connects with Safari 11 and IE 10 (or some similar combination).

Comment: And _"Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."_

Answer (score 0):

First, to make it easier, create a column "position" and make sure they are numbered as they were inserted, like this :

```
+-------+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|  pos  | Users | Application |      Name      | Value  |
+-------+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|  1    | A1    | AA          | browsername    | IE     |
|  2    | A1    | AA          | browserVersion | 11     |
|  3    | A1    | AA          | browsername    | chrome |
|  4    | A1    | AA          | browserVersion | 60     |
|  5    | A1    | AA          | browsername    | safari |
|  6    | A1    | AA          | browserVersion | 11     |
|  7    | A2    | AA          | browsername    | IE     |
|  8    | A2    | AA          | browserVersion | 10     |
|  9    | A2    | AA          | browsername    | safari |
|  10   | A2    | AA          | browserVersion | 10     |
|  11   | A3    | AA          | browsername    | IE     |
|  12   | A3    | AA          | browserVersion | 9      |
|  13   | A3    | AA          | browsername    | chrome |
|  14   | A3    | AA          | browserVersion | 60     |
|  15   | A1    | AA          | browsername    | safari |
|  16   | A1    | AA          | browserVersion | 11     |
|  17   | A1    | AA          | browsername    | IE     |
|  18   | A1    | AA          | browserVersion | 10     |
+-------+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
```

Now, you can use the CTE and lead function to obtain what you want.

```
;with X as ( 
   select users, application, name, value as Browser, lead (value) over (order by pos) as Version 
   from table 
   where name = 'browsername'
)
select * 
from X
where browser = 'IE' and version = '11'
```

PS: always create an identity column, it always pays off in the long run

Comment: Why you use a CTE since you are selecting from `table`?

Comment: And you should quote `[user]`,it's `Users` not `User` btw

Comment: If you're going to change the table the obvious thing to do would be to include browserName and browserValue as columns!